# After Adding a few Clips to the timeline, audio is no longer imported?

Tags: premiere, canon

I'm using Premiere Pro CC 2014 trial to evaluate if I want to switch from Vegas Pro 2012 to the Adobe Suite. I'm editing a short video I made in Denver, CO this past summer that I shot with two cameras; the Canon 550D, and the DMC-LX5. After adding a few clips to the timeline (approximately 15 or more), every video after that does not have an audio track automatically added but does have a video track. I'm simply dragging and dropping videos to a single sequence. If you play the videos in the project window, they play with audio. What's going on?

Thanks,

Adobe Newb

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your UI?

Comment: @AJHenderson Sure, here ya go: http://i.imgur.com/kRIBdeO.jpg

Comment: Ok, what about the media info of the clips that aren't working.  I noticed they aren't showing on the left hand side atm, though the actual properties would be even more telling.  For some reason it seems that it isn't recognizing the audio because the timeline itself looks fine.

Comment: Those are just two clips that aren't working. Literally every video you place on the timeline afterwards has this issue. In fact, so far in the video, every single file has been from the DMC-LX5, no 550D yet. So every video has had the same audio properties thus far.

Comment: Can you try import clips from a different source and see if they have the same error? Also a Mediainfo output would be helpful.
http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Comment: also, what happens if you try a new timeline.  Can the files be added to any timeline and have audio?  Do the clips that previously worked work if you try adding them again?

Comment: @AJHenderson OK, so I'm retarded. It's 550D footage that's getting messed up w/audio because the timeline is set by the DMC-LX5's audio settings. Any way to make the sequence a little less rigorous when it comes to audio settings?

Comment: It surprises me that it didn't take care of that automatically.  Does the 550D audio work in a sequence that is setup for it?  Can you post the details of the audio formats for both?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has this concept of "target tracks" in the sequence window.  On the left side of the media locked/unlocked icon is the "source patching for inserts and overwrites".  On the right side of the media locked/unlocked icon is the "toggle track targeting for this track".  When off, the track name (such as V1 or V2 or A1 or A2) is gray and when on, it's blue.

Chances are good that you left those targeting features well enough alone, and the Adobe defaults are to indeed enable track targeting for your tracks.  When track targeting is blue for only empty tracks, inserting a new video clip does just what you'd expect: it puts the new video and audio into unused tracks.  However, if targeting is on for tracks that already have audio, then when you go to insert the new clip does what you might not expect: it just overwrites the audio clip of the targeted track and that's that.  It does not create a new track for your audio.  If you've inserted 15 clips, it's quite possible that you have audio only from the last clip you added, and that it overwrote the 14th clip's audio track which overwrote the 13th clip's audio track, etc.

There's an answer on VP as to how to restore the lost audio clips ([Adobe Premiere - Restore Audio to A/V Clip After Deleting](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/adobe-premiere-restore-audio-to-a-v-clip-after-deleting)).  My answer explains how to not do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You experience this basically because Adobe changed its functionality on CC version. And this is called **Source Patching And Track Targeting**.

**Solution:**
Highlight A1 or A2 in timeline. That is it.

[image]

**More information about this.**
In link find what adobe staff says. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1422503?tstart=0

**A training from adobe.**
https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/source-patching-track-targetting.html

**A training in youtube.**